# Where is Newman-Conway Sequence used?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I read on multiple sources like https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/n/n078.htm and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/newman-conway-sequence/ and multiple other websites which show up when I google "Newman-Conway Sequence", "Newman-Conway Sequence Uses" but I don't find any website that explains what exactly that sequence is for.

Does this have any application apart from teaching programmers about recurrence relations? This question was asked for me in an interview where I was shown this series, asked to write a program to print it and asked if I can think of any place where this can be used.

While writing the program was easy, I just wanted to know if there is any use for this series. If this is not the right place to ask this, kindly suggest where I have to ask this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A004001 . I don't see any plausible applications on there. Conway had a broad interest in chaotic integer sequences, so I think it was probably a testing ground for combinatorics techniques mostly.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for your response.